# 2D plot using Manipulate command

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, expression-manipulation

Can anyone tell me what the problem is with the following code:

```
y[x_ a_] := Sin[x (1 + a x)]
Manipulate[Plot[y[x a], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}]
```

However, the following code gives me the desired output?

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}]
```

Many thanks

Comment: comma missing in between `y[x_ a_]` should be `y[x_,a_]` and also in the plot should be `y[x,a]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Putting comma does not help either. I tried with the following code, however, no success.                                                                                y[x_, a_] := Sin[x (1 + a x)]
Manipulate[Plot[y[x, a], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}]

Comment: The code in the comment totally works for me :-) Just don't forget a linebreak between the function definition and `Manipulate`

Comment: Problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't noticed @Histogram's comment, which was basically this solution:

```
y[x_, a_] := Sin[x (1 + a x)];
Manipulate[Plot[y[x, a], {x, 0, 6}], 
{a, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks, Histogram.                                                                                                                                @Michael, Is it the way I should acknowledge Histogram? Sorry, I am new  here. :)

Comment: @Arafin I think that Michael 's comment was directed at David, rather than at you :-)

Comment: @ArafinArif My comment was just concerning this answer and was alluding to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  As you may have noticed, users are not usually notified of a response in a comment if the "@user" is omitted.  But maybe the thanks you expressed under your question is enough.